# Help and advice needed working with Quartz.NET NthIncludedDayTrigger

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I've started using Quartz.NET recently, and so far, it's been really 
helpful. Now, I'm trying to use it to create a job that runs once a 
month using a NthIncludedDayTrigger (I want to use the 
NthIncludedDayTrigger as eventually I will be specifying a calendar to 
exclude weekends/holidays).

To familiarise myself with the code, I've 
set up a simple console application to create an NthIncludedDayTrigger 
where the first fire time will be 15 seconds from now:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.DefaultScheduler; 
    scheduler.Start();

    var jobDetail = new JobDetail("Job name", "Group name", typeof(SomeIJobImplementation)); 
    var trigger = new NthIncludedDayTrigger(); 
    trigger.Name = "Trigger name"; 
    trigger.MisfireInstruction = MisfireInstruction.NthIncludedDayTrigger.DoNothing; 
    trigger.IntervalType = NthIncludedDayTrigger.IntervalTypeMonthly; 

    //I'm using the following while experimenting with the code (AddHour(1) to account for BST): 
    trigger.FireAtTime =  DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1).AddSeconds(15).ToString("HH:mm:ss"); 

    //I'm using the following while experimenting with the code: 
    trigger.N = DateTime.Today.Day;

    Console.WriteLine("Started, press any key to stop ..."); 
    Console.ReadKey(); 

    scheduler.Shutdown(false); 
} 

...

public class SomeIJobImplementation : IJob 
{ 
    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context) 
    { 
            Logger.Write(String.Format(
                "Job executed called at {0}", 
                DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")), null, 1, 
                TraceEventType.Information); 
    } 
}
```

Running this results in the job being executed multiple times 
(approximately once per second) for one minute. I'm using an ADO.NET 
job store and can see in my database that QRTZ_TRIGGERS.NEXT_FIRE_TIME 
is set to the last executed time, i.e. doesn't seem to be scheduled to 
run again.

I expected the above code to run the job once (after about 15 
seconds), then schedule the job to run again in one months time.

Perphaps the issue is just with the way I'm using Quartz.NET whilst 
I've been experimenting or, maybe, my expectations are wrong? Either 
way, I would be most grateful for any help/suggestions to explain the 
behaviour I've observed, and what I need to change to get the 
behaviour I want.

Answer (score 1):

I must be late but I was trying to implement the same solution and ended up here. 
I reckon you should star the scheduler after you've defined jobs and triggers.